# AWS import images vhd,vmdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, image, import, vhd, vmdk

I have problem with import vm images to aws.
I getting problem like this below. I checked many times roles, polices and etc. I try many images and none of them worked

```
{
    "ImportImageTasks": [
        {
            "Description": "TC",
            "ImportTaskId": "import-ami-xxx",
            "SnapshotDetails": [
                {
                    "Description": "TC",
                    "DiskImageSize": 42754671616.0,
                    "Format": "VHD",
                    "Status": "deleted",
                    "UserBucket": {
                        "S3Bucket": "vmdk-images",
                        "S3Key": "TC-Ubuntu-16.04_Disk1_Mon--15-Feb-2021-at-23-00-03-(UTC-+01-00).vhd"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Status": "deleted",
            "StatusMessage": "ClientError:Footers not identical.",
            "Tags": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That message specifically is pointing a potential problem with your exported image. More here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-troubleshooting.html

Comment: It was problem with VM file.